# Get the tags as an array, convert the tag into a string, and then replace spaces with dash

Tags: tags

I am trying to get the tags from the post (there will only be one tag), then create a new variable with that tag name but with the spaces replaced with dashes.

This is what a have so far, but I cannot get it to display the value of the tag (both with spaces and without) instead of "Array". In the code below, I'm only trying to get it to display with the dashes right now.

```
        $posttags = get_the_tags();
        $newname = str_replace(' ', '-', $posttags);
        if ($posttags) {
          foreach ($posttags as $tag){
            echo 'Post by: <a href="/meet-the-team/employees/'. $newname .'/">'. $newname .'</a>';
          }
        }
```

Comment: `get_the_tags` will return an array even if there's only a single tag, aka a list of 1 is still a list, in cases like these you need to break down each step and check your assumptions ( e.g. that `$posttags` is a string, not an array. In fact it would be a `WP_Term` object, not a string  )

Comment: I figured it out.. I was on the right track but I didnt realize I needed to specific the $tag->name inside of the str_replace...

            $posttags = get_the_tags();
            if ($posttags) {
              foreach ($posttags as $tag){
                $newname = strtolower(str_replace(' ', '-', $tag->name));
                echo 'Post by: <a href="/meet-the-team/employees/'.$newname.'">'. $tag->name .'</a>';
              }
            }

Answer (score 3):

Lets break this apart using your question title:

> Get the tags as an array, convert the tag into a string, and then replace spaces with dash

### Get the tags as an array

`get_the_tags` is the correct function, you now have one of 2 things:

- an array of term objects ( a tag is a term in the tags taxonomy )
- `false`, there are no tags on this post
- A `WP_Error` object, something went wrong

So we need to check for those cases, afterall if we assume tags are returned but there are none, what will happen? We have to tell it what will happen or undefined things will happen, and that could be anything, probably a 500 error

So lets update the first bit of code:

```
$tags = get_the_tags();

if ( is_wp_error( $tags ) ) {
    return; // there was an error
}
if ( false === $tags ) {
    return; // there were no tags on this post
}
// now we can do stuff with the tags
```

### Convert The Tag into a string

Nifty, now we have an array of tags. You mentioned there should only be 1 tag, but who knows what plugins might be adding their own tags, so lets make sure your code handles that correctly:

```
foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
    // do something with our tag
    break; // exit after the first one
}
```

### Replace the spaces with dashes

Each `$tag` is a `WP_Term` object, you can use the terms slug with `$tag->name`, which will already have the URL friendly version

However, why bother? There's a function for that! We can replace this:

```
echo 'Post by: <a href="/meet-the-team/employees/'. $newname .'/">'. $newname .'</a>';
```

With:

```
$url = get_term_link( $tag, 'tags' );
echo 'Post by: <a href="'.esc_url( $url ).'">'.esc_html( $tag->name ).'</a>';
```

Notice I added escaping. Escaping is important and will prevent most hacks. Despite it's anti-hacking superpowers, it's almost never applied to WordPress code :(

Comment: Only thing missing is a "so to wrap it all up," but, on the other hand, this isn't Smashing or Tuts, where I think you'd need a download link, too - so: Very nice!

Comment: @CKMacLeod problem with that is it gives everyone copypasta, and nobody learns anything. Then the requirements change in a trivial way and they have no idea what to do and come back asking you to update a word, e.g. "it says Post by: but I need it to say Page by:, can you change the code for me?". I'm sure sk03 doesn't need me to pre-assemble it all though :) Though a further reading section is always nice to have

Answer (score 1):

If you use `str_replace` on an array, you get an array back. So `$newname` is rightly an array.

You may want to do the `str_replace` inside your `foreach` loop instead - that way it works on each individual item and then you display the individual item.

Or, if you keep using `str_replace` on the full array, you need to change your `foreach` loop to: `foreach($newname as $tag)` and echo `$tag` not `$newname`.

Comment: get_the_tags() returns an array of tag objects, not tag names. So, I'll answer below, I guess.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll remove my question. I figured it out. Just needed to put $tag->name inside of str_replace instead of just $tag.

Comment: @sk03 don't remove your question, then nobody would learn, besides, there are other things you need to do that you've missed

Comment: @tomjnowell I agree with keeping it, but in similar situations in the past, people who commented on my questions were pretty rude about deleting the question once it's solved (either quickly or by myself). Those were on the main stackoverflow site, not the WP site so I'm glad you guys are understanding that stuff like this does help people learn. Maybe upvote the question or my comment/answer? I'd really appreciate it

Comment: @sk03 you can always answer your own question, you even get a badge on your profile for doing it :) Haters gonna hate, if they're nasty about it flag the comment but don't feel the need to delete a question